# how do i maximize an image similar to the effect of using an img tag?

Tags: javascript, html, css, image

How can you maximize an image throughout the whole page in the browser using CSS like `<img src="image.jpg" width="1000" height="1000">` does without having to rely on how much the user's browser is zoomed in/out and so that when the image covers the whole page, a right click will show the options it gives are:

```
save image as, copy image url, copy image, open image in new tab, search google for this image, print
```

instead of `back,forward,reload,save as,print,translate to english,view source code (disabled),view page info`.
The previous previous options are what are given when you right click on an image such as https://i.stack.imgur.com/1r9nk.jpg, i want to somehow offer those options only regardless of where the user right clicks/how much he zooms out/zooms inside the page containing the desired image that includes some html in the background (not visible to the user).
thanks.

Answer (score 0):

```
<style>img{position:fixed; height:100%: width:100%;}</style>
<img src="image.jpg">
```